# Shiny Dynamic tabs dependent on other tabs How to create them simultaneously

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a tab which has car and depending on which car I select a list of years will appear (which also depends on which car I selected)

Now I have already created this dependany

But  I also have a slider for creating as many car tabs and related year tabs

All tabs respond to the slider.

However I want to create them in pairs. So If I increase from 2 to 3 in slider selection. I want to create 3 car tabs together with 3 related year tabs

So a pair of tabs (car and year) are created together and they should be under each other. I would like it to be as

```
cars:
Year:

cars:
Year:
```

Right now It is

```
cars:
cars:
Year:
Year:
```

Any help is much appreciated

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)    

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(),

                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sliderInput("integer", "numbtabs:",min=1,max=10,value=2),


             menuItem(uiOutput("select_inputs"),
             uiOutput("select_inputs2"))    

                    ),dashboardBody( fluidRow(box()       )))

server <- function(input, output){

  observeEvent(input$integer, output$select_inputs <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:input$integer, function(i){
      selectInput(paste0('cars',    i),
                 "cars:",list("Select"="","a"="mazda","b"="ford"))


    })

  })



  )

  observeEvent(input$integer, output$select_inputs2 <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:input$integer, function(i){
       if(input[[paste0('cars', i)]]=="mazda"){a=list("Select"="","201amazda1"="FYmazda11", "201aaa2"="FY12")}
else if(input[[paste0('cars', i)]]=="ford"){a=list("Select"="","2001"="FYFORd11", "201FORD2"="FY1200")}
      selectInput(paste0('year1',    i),"year:",a)

    })


  }))

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using [shiny modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html). Basically, you first create a module for a single cars/year selection and then include it several times.

The module consists of a "server-part" and an "ui-part" showing two dropdown menus. The choices of the second dropdown menu depend on the selection in the first one according to your example.

```
carYearUi <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  wellPanel(
    selectInput( 
      ns('cars'), "cars:", list("Select" = "", "a" = "mazda", "b" = "ford")),
    uiOutput(ns('year'))
  )
}

carYearServer <- function(input, output, session){
  ns <- session$ns

  output$year = renderUI({
    if(input$cars == "mazda")
      choices <- list("Select" = "","201amazda1" = "FYmazda11", "201aaa2" = "FY12")
    else
      choices <- list("Select" = "", "2001" = "FYFORd11", "201FORD2" = "FY1200")
    selectInput(ns('year'), "year:", choices)
  })
}
```

The rest of the app creates a slider and uses `uiOutput` to create a dynamic number of `carYear` instances.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("slider","how much cars?", 1, 8, 1, width = "100%" ),
  uiOutput("selectors")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  # setup the servers for the modules
  for(i in 1:8)
    callModule(carYearServer, i)

  # create dynamic ui which shows all the dropdown boxes
  output$selectors <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:input$slider, carYearUi)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The selections of the dropdown menus can be acessed through the IDs `1-cars`, `1-year`, `2-cars`, ..., `8-year`. Alternatively, you can also use the `NS` function to aquire the IDs: `NS(1, "cars")`, ..., `NS(8, "year")`

[image: The app in action]

### About the follow up question

Here is a solution using `reactiveValues` inside the `carYearServer` function. I needed to move some code from the `carYearUi` to `carYearServer` as well. Note that the module itself takes care of the storage, so it is not necessary to change the rest of the code (`ui <- ...`, `server <- ...`)

```
library(shiny)

carYearUi <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  wellPanel(
    uiOutput(ns('cars')),
    uiOutput(ns('year'))
  )
}

carYearServer <- function(input, output, session){
  ns <- session$ns
  storage <- reactiveValues()      ## initialize
  output$year = renderUI({
    if(identical(input$cars, "mazda"))
      choices <- list("Select" = "","201amazda1" = "FYmazda11", "201aaa2" = "FY12")
    else
      choices <- list("Select" = "", "2001" = "FYFORd11", "201FORD2" = "FY1200")
    selectInput(
      ns('year'), "year:", choices, 
      selected = storage$year     ## get 
    )
  })
  output$cars <- renderUI({
    selectInput( 
      ns('cars'), "cars:", list("Select" = "", "a" = "mazda", "b" = "ford"),
      selected = storage$car       ## get
    )
  })
  observe({
    storage$year <- input$year     ## set
    storage$car <- input$cars      ## set
  })
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `shiny::updateSelectInput` or `outputOptions(..., suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks Gregor de Cillia. I did not know about Shiny modules. learning a lot. Thanks for your help

Comment: I had a follow up question to this. say my inputslider is at 3 and  I select some values in the 3 drop down tabs and then If I want to add another drop down I increase the slider to 4. But this then refreshes all my previous selection in the first three tabs. I tried thinking of using obserevent but that doesnt seem to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: There are several ways to archieve this. I updated my answer to demonstrate one way (using `reactiveValues` and `observe`). The new part of the answer begins with the title **About the follow up question**.

Comment: Thanks Gregor for the clear explanation.This was very helpful